# Print JavaScript condition used in Shiny conditionalPanel

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm creating a conditionalPanel in a Shiny app. I'm attempting to debug the JavaScript condition, but without inspecting it, I'm just guessing random JavaScript bits. Is there a way to inspect the condition directly?

```
selectizeInput('groups','Groups:',
                   choices = list('Choice1' = 'choice1','Choice2' = 'choice2'),
                   multiple = TRUE,selected = NULL
)

conditionalPanel(
          print("input.groups.indexOf('choice2') >= 0"), # desired output
          condition = "input.groups.indexOf('choice2') >= 0",
          selectInput("statusfilter", "StatusFilter",
                      list("NewChoice1" = "nc1","NewChoice2" = "nc2"))
)
```

The above code (generalized from my production code) is showing the conditionalPanel at start up before I even click a choice. Once I do, it will disappear until I choose 'choice2'. If I could inspect the condition, I could fix this quickly.

Answer (score 2):

After commenting our the print statement so that the code runs, if you open your javascript console, you'll see an error:

`Error parsing expression: input.groups.indexOf('choice2') >= 0`

This suggests your JS code breaks. This is because `input.groups` is null , and doing `.indexOf` on a null value causes an error.

So what you want in the condition is:

`condition = "input.groups !== null && input.groups.indexOf('choice2') >= 0"`

Comment: That makes sense! I tried to make the question more about the general debugging option, which maybe I failed at. I saw lots of similar questions that wouldn't have been asked if they knew where to look for themselves. If you can edit your answer to emphasize your use of the JS console to debug, I think it would better answer the general question. It's really helpful you answered the specific question though!

Comment: well I didn't really do any debugging, I just opened the console as a default first step and saw the error. Very often errors (in javascript and R alike) in code that seems innocent arise because of trying to do something to a null value, so I assumed that was the case, checked, and yep.